# how can I launch a specific activity from a different app without leaving the app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose, intentfilter

I want to start an app which has multiple launchers/shortcuts, I have tried  packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage() but it starts the default main activity of that app that too outside my app.

I haven't worked a lot with core android concepts. is there a way to do this?

[example of one such apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOHrY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to use Intent https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

This is example how you could start new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.yourapp", "com.example.yourapp.SecondActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Technically, when you launch an activity from another app, you're not "leaving" your app in the sense that your app is being shut down, the new activity is simply placed on top of the activity stack.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the activity i want to start is not from my app, example : there is a app called phonePe (photo attached to question) i want to start "Scan a QR" directly from my app

Comment: I see. You can only start activities of other apps if those activities are exported (with android:exported="true"). Most apps won't export sensitive activities for security reasons.
Given that PhonePe is a financial app, it's likely they have security measures in place.
Unless PhonePe has documented this kind of integration for developers or you've inspected the app's manifest and found the right intent structure, you may not be able to directly launch the "Scan a QR" activity.

Comment: oh, okay I understand it now, thanks for the time!